# navPage.SetHideNavigationBarSeparator(true) no longer works in Xamarin 4.5 latest any solution for that, not working the below code

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

```
public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Element == null) return;

            NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please add more explanation with your code about your question.  Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the code into ViewDidLayoutSubviews method .

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

        if(this.NavigationBar != null)
        {
            NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        }
    }
```